# Writing a clipboard viewer in C#

Tags: c#, keylogger

I want to write program to learn vocabulary. Simply each time, when I copy a word to clipboard, It will save them to text file.

so, there are requirements, I think that is:

1. My program run in background like keylogger?
2. Detect even and save words to text file everytime I copy a word to clipboard.?

all done by C#.
so, plz give me some advice! thank you very much!

Comment: "I want to write program to learn vocabulary. Simply each time..." - What? That's the best you could come up with?

Comment: That's not a keylogger, in MS Windows it's called a clipboard viewer.

Comment: 1. yep, sorry for my English.
2. thanks u.

Answer (score 7):

There's an example in the .NET SDK called ClipboardSpy.

Here's an example even:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            string s = Clipboard.GetText();

            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Detect even and save words to text
>   file everytime I copy a word to
>   clipboard.?

To detect clipboard changes use the [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052(VS.85).aspx).
Here are instructions of how to create a clipboard viewer in C#:
[Create a Windows Clipboard Monitor in C# using SetClipboardViewer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx)